# Deployed to fly.io, but not compiled

Tags: docker, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7, daisyui, fly

I am Japanese.
My English is poor, so I apologize if it is not clear.

The layout of the application deployed in the production environment is broken.

**The source code is as follows**

- [yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.19.cjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM76W.png)

Since there are more than 10,000 lines of code, we will put some of them in the image.

- .dockerignore

```
# See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file for more about ignoring files.

# Ignore git directory.
/.git/

# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore all default key files.
/config/master.key
/config/credentials/*.key

# Ignore all environment files.
/.env*
!/.env.example

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*
/tmp/*
!/log/.keep
!/tmp/.keep

# Ignore pidfiles, but keep the directory.
/tmp/pids/*
!/tmp/pids/
!/tmp/pids/.keep

# Ignore storage (uploaded files in development and any SQLite databases).
/storage/*
!/storage/.keep
/tmp/storage/*
!/tmp/storage/
!/tmp/storage/.keep

# Ignore assets.
/node_modules/
/app/assets/builds/*
!/app/assets/builds/.keep
/public/assets
```

- Dockerfile

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1

# Make sure RUBY_VERSION matches the Ruby version in .ruby-version and Gemfile
ARG RUBY_VERSION=3.1.2
FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-slim as base

# Rails app lives here
WORKDIR /rails

# Set production environment
ENV RAILS_ENV="production" \
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test" \
    BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT="1"

# Update gems and bundler
RUN gem update --system --no-document && \
    gem install -N bundler


# Throw-away build stage to reduce size of final image
FROM base as build

# Install packages needed to build gems and node modules
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential curl libpq-dev node-gyp pkg-config python-is-python3

# Install JavaScript dependencies
ARG NODE_VERSION=19.0.0
ARG YARN_VERSION=1.22.19
ENV PATH=/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/nodenv/node-build/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp/ && \
    /tmp/node-build-master/bin/node-build "${NODE_VERSION}" /usr/local/node && \
    npm install -g yarn@$YARN_VERSION && \
    rm -rf /tmp/node-build-master

# Install application gems
COPY --link Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install && \
    bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile && \
    rm -rf ~/.bundle/ $BUNDLE_PATH/ruby/*/cache $BUNDLE_PATH/ruby/*/bundler/gems/*/.git

# Install node modules
COPY --link package.json package-lock.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Copy application code
COPY --link . .

# Precompile bootsnap code for faster boot times
RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile app/ lib/

# Precompiling assets for production without requiring secret RAILS_MASTER_KEY
RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE=DUMMY ./bin/rails assets:precompile
RUN rm -f /rails/tmp/pids/server.pid

# Final stage for app image
FROM base

# Install packages needed for deployment
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y postgresql-client && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives

# Run and own the application files as a non-root user for security
RUN useradd rails --home /rails --shell /bin/bash
USER rails:rails

# Copy built artifacts: gems, application
COPY --from=build /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle
COPY --from=build --chown=rails:rails /rails /rails

# Deployment options
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT="1" \
    RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES="true"

# Entrypoint prepares the database.
ENTRYPOINT ["/rails/bin/docker-entrypoint"]

# Start the server by default, this can be overwritten at runtime
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["./bin/rails", "server"]
```

- package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "author": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.2.1",
    "tom-select": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/tailwind.css"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.19"
}
```

- .yarnrc

```
# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
# yarn lockfile v1


yarn-path ".yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.19.cjs"
```

Dockerfile, .dockerignore, .yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.19.cjs, and .yarnrc were created with the docker-compose exec api bin/rails generate dockerfile command.

[Reference Articles](https://fly.io/docs/rails/getting-started/dockerfiles/#:%7E:text=rerun)

I thought the layout was broken by loading .yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.19.cjs.

Therefore, we deleted this file and changed some parts of the Dockerfile.

```
# Install JavaScript dependencies
ARG NODE_VERSION=19.0.0
ARG YARN_VERSION=1.22.19
ENV PATH=/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/nodenv/node-build/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp/ && \
    /tmp/node-build-master/bin/node-build "${NODE_VERSION}" /usr/local/node && \
    npm install -g yarn@$YARN_VERSION && \
    rm -rf /tmp/node-build-master
```

However, no solution was reached.
I am unable to resolve this issue to my knowledge.
I would be glad to learn from you.